# While loop on multi-dimensional array

Tags: php

So I have a function that currently has a foreach and it works amazing, but I'm being forced to change it to a while loop:

**PLEASE NOTE**: *The developers at my company don't want to use the foreach and they think that a while loop would be more efficient, but I'm not understanding how that would be executed, so I need some help*.

**So I have the following function** (`$post_blocks` is an array of arrays):

```
public function parse_block_data(string $block_name, string $selector, $post_id)
{
    if (!has_blocks($post_id)) {
        return false;
    }
    $post_blocks = parse_blocks(get_the_content('', false, $post_id));
    foreach ($post_blocks as $block) {
        if ($block_name != $block['blockName']) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!isset($block['attrs']['id'])) {
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($block['attrs']['data'][$selector])) {
            return $block['attrs']['data'][$selector];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It uses the parameters to build up an array as shown below:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzLdE.png)

So I started building a while loop inside the function, but I'm clueless on how to achieve it without using a foreach or if it's even possible, so I replaced the foreach with:

```
// I get the 9 counts of $post_blocks correctly.

$block = 0;
while ($block < count($post_blocks)) 

    // If the $block_name doesn't match `blockName` value inside the multi-dimensional array, then continue iterating until the end and then return false.

    // If ['attrs']['id'] is not set, return false.

    // At last, if we have a blockName and a ID and the selector is set, return ['attrs']['data'][$selector]

}
```

All help will be appreciated! It makes no sense to me, but if someone can assist, I'd be forever grateful!

Comment: Did you ask a similar question earlier today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically the same as your `foreach` loop, you just set the iteration variable by indexing the array, and increment the index manually.

```
$block_num = 0;
while ($block_num < count($post_blocks)) {
    $block = $post_blocks[$block_num];
    if ($block_name == $block['blockName']) {
        if (!isset($block['attrs']['id'])) {
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($block['attrs']['data'][$selector])) {
            return $block['attrs']['data'][$selector];
        } else {
            break;
        }    
    }

    $block_num++;
}
```

I'm not sure why your colleagues think this is preferable.

If there's a company coding style they want you to follow, why don't you ask them what it should be?

Comment: To me it seems like it's all like PHP5-6 styling and I'm trying to advance with PHP 7 & 8 - Seems to be going backwards, but this worked! Is `continue` also used in while loops? I think the reason they wanted a while loop is to move from using continue/break, should I just iterate there then?

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing in PHP 7/8 that would simplify this.

Comment: I got rid of `continue` by inverting the `if` test.

Comment: Your the man! But now they will complain that there are nested if statements which they hate, their motto - So it seems like I can't win at all, their saying: `Eliminate all choices by returning early`.

Comment: The only way to get rid of the `break` is if the `while` condition itself expressed the opposite of the breaking conditions. But since that's nested in multiple conditions, it would be very complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance at atleast, it's much appreciated, I will accept this answer as it did answer my question, but I will look and see if there if anyway that I can have a non-nested, non continue/break function - They're making things complicated.

Comment: You really need to ask your colleagues what they're looking for. it seems to me like they're trying to apply a coding style requirement where it doesn't fit.